# using ionic-angular module in angular app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular5

is it possible to use 'ionic-angular' in an angular app ?

and how to include it correctly?

- cause right now i'm using it and it works fine in development mode (ng-serve) but it does not work when i build and upload to the server

my package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/common": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/core": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/http": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/platform-server": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/router": "^7.0.2",
"@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0-beta.15",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.5.0",
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.0.2",
"@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "^6.1.0",
"angular-toastr": "^2.1.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
"core-js": "^2.5.7",
"jspdf": "^1.4.1",
"ngx-cookie": "^4.1.2",
"ngx-drupal7-services": "^1.6.0",
"ngx-infinite-scroll": "^6.0.1",
"ngx-toastr": "^9.0.2",
"rxjs": "^6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
"saucelabs": "^1.5.0",
"toastr": "^2.1.4",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.4",
"@angular/cli": "^7.0.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.2",
"@angular/language-service": "^7.0.2",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.9",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/jspdf": "^1.1.31",
"@types/node": "^10.12.2",
"codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"karma": "^3.1.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"protractor": "^5.4.1",
"ts-node": "~5.0.1",
"tslint": "^5.11.0",
"typescript": "^3.1.6"
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to say? I think the answer is probably yes

Comment: i'm trying to use 'ionic-angular' module in angular app but in production it is not working

Comment: can you give me some example on what are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to use the modules' platform and events classes

Comment: that's package.json after i removed it and installed @ionic/angular and did not work either ,, so what to do

Answer (score 0):

yes, check ngx rocket generator they have support to use cordova plugins api without ionic ui framework https://github.com/ngx-rocket/generator-ngx-rocket